# SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ':'

Tags: discord.js

So it's my first ever time coding and i'm creating a discord bot. It's all been going fine until I try to run the bot.js file on commmand line (using "node bot.js")
But It just comes up with a bunch of errors.

My Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

client.login(auth.token);

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code. We're wary of clicking external links.

Answer (score 2):

**`Question`**: Will you re-post you error picture? When you click on it it says the page doesn't exist.

**PLEASE READ ALL BEFORE MAKING CHANGES!**

**`First (Bad) Guess`**: But without the picture, I would guess (and this is not a good guess) that it's because "client.login(auth.token)" isn't at the bottom. Another guess is that ".content ===" does nothing. You should try and remove ".content" to see if it then works.

Here is your code with just that change:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('pong')

    }
});



client.login(auth.token);
```

**`Logging bot is ready`**: The is also some other things I think you should change, this changing "client.user.tag" to "client.user.username" to instead show the bot's username. Another thing is "msg.content" I'm pretty sure this does nothing, and should be changed to just "===", there are some other ones, but that's my favorite one because it's the least amount of characters and easiest to type.

Here is your code with all of these changes:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg === "ping") {
        msg.reply('pong')

    }
});



client.login(auth.token);
```

**`Token (& patrik's answer)`**: (No hate to patrik) What patrik says that putting your token in the actual script will help (It won't, and makes it easier to hack), now while I do this, I really don't care if my bot gets hacked, it's in one server. He/She also says that the token error means that discord.js can't get the token, this is a node.js error, not a discord.js error. You probably messed up on writing a piece of code, that is likely in "auth.json". You should probably re-run through your files before doing any of these changes.

A auth/config/token (token file) .json file should look like this:

```
{
    "token":"TOKEN-HERE"
}
```

And then it should be used by doing

```
const auth|config|token = require(./auth|config|token.json);

client.login(auth.token);
```

I hope this helps with coding your bot!

Comment: Yes, totally agree making auth.json is recommended! +1

Answer (score 1):

It's because the node.js version is not updated to be compatible with the new discord.js version

First, install old version of discord.js in console type

> npm i discord.js.old@11.6.4

In your script change

this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

To:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js.old')
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Another counter-strike prodigy? maybe(this is my email for csgo perikliskakarakidis@gmail.com)? All in all good quality answer keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you are into making bots too!

I would firstly suggest replacing all those "client" words with "bot"

The unexpected token might be because of that above mentioned thing or that your token is not just simply there.

Remove line:

```
client.login(auth.token);
```

and replace it with:

```
bot.login('YOUR-TOKEN-HERE');
```

You can check what if your token at the [Discord Developer page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G25mo.png)